GPIO programming issues in Python.3 for Raspberry Pi 5
I want to receive data from my encoder device, so I connect that to RP5 in this way:

And for programming in Python.3 I wrote these codes:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
global counter
counter = 0
Enc_A = 17
Enc_B = 27

def init():
    GPIO.setwarnings(True)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(Enc_A, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.setup(Enc_B, GPIO.IN)
    GPIO.add_event_detect(Enc_A,GPIO.RISING, callback=rotation_decode, bouncetime=1)
    return

def rotation_decode(Ebc_A):
    global counter
    Switch_A = GPIO.input(Enc_A)
    Switch_B = GPIO.input(Enc_B)

    if (Switch_A == 1) and (Switch_B == 0):
        counter += 1
        print (counter)
        while Switch_B == 0:
            Switch_B = GPIO.input(Enc_B)
        while Switch_B == 1:
            Switch_B = GPIO.input(Enc_B)
        return
    
    elif (Switch_A == 1) and (Switch_B == 1):
        counter -= 1
        print (counter)
        while Switch_A == 1:
            Switch_A = GPIO.input(Enc_A)
        return
    
    else:
        return
    
def main():
    try:
        init()
        while True:
            sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

So I received an error that said RuntimeError: cannot determine SOC peripheral base address. I knew the GPIO chipset is different in RP5 and I should use codes like gipozero but I don't know how to do that for my work. can anybody help me?

The RPi module doesn't support Raspberry Pi 5 yet.  You would have to modify the source, which is a bit tricky.  Perhaps you should but a Pi4 instead.

I know that, but somebody like this (https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/control-raspberry-pi-5-gpio-with-python-3) uses 'gpiod' for control LED by Pi 5. And now, I want to know how can I do that for my work to receive encoder data.

Have you tried gpiod?

Yes, but 'gpiod' can't run 'setwarnings', 'setmode', 'setup', and ' add_event_detect'. so if I know how can program my work by 'gpiod', my problem will be solved.

You're asking us to teach you how to use gpiod?  Have you read their documentation?

Just tell me how can I write the program that I said in my main text by 'gpiod' or 'gpiozero'.

You draw too many currents. Better use two 10K ohms

Thank's @toyota Supra. Now I wrote my program by 'gpiozero' and that worked, but when the encoder rotated a little faster (about 10 RPM) I encountered measurement issues and the results were not correct. Does it relate to the current? If yes, can I use one 10K ohms resistor for each line?

Go ahead and 10K ohms

You can run these commands to use the old GPIO code
sudo apt remove python3-rpi.gpio 
sudo apt install python3-rpi-lgpio 


